# Resolving JSTL attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I want to dynamically generate model attribute name and use it in JSP.

For eq:

```
for (Integer integer : integers){    
    model.addAttribute("model_" + integer, integer);
}
```

model.setAttribute("integers",integers);

in jsp:

```
<c:foreach  items=${integers} var=integer>
 ${model_integer} // Want to Print the value but throwing error.
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: Why to want separate model attribute for every integer?
You can directly add integers collection/Array as model attribute. and retrieve using JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<c:foreach  items=${integers} var=integer>
    <c:set var="totalBuild" value="${0}"/>
    <c:set var="totalBuild" value="${totalBuild + integer "/>
    <c:set var="modelAtt" value="model_${totalBuild}" />
    ${modelAtt} 
</c:foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

To print out the value you'll need to use the out tag

```
<!-- You need to surround the values of your attributes with quotes -->
<c:foreach  items="${integers}" var="integer">
    <c:out value="${integer}" /> <!-- the var name in the for each" -->
</c:foreach>
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm

You should also add the integers to a list of some sort, then add the list as a model attribute.